# Main Menu Items --> Change "About" Credits.rtf after change his type

Tags: xcode, cocoa, menuitem

I have (for me) interesting problem, in Cocoa Project I created file "Credits.rtf" for testing custom text for this window... but I tried to change type from Credits.rtf to Credits.html and after this (even when I delete file and reference to this file too) the "About" window always showing below mentioned text and I dont know how is the way to change it, even when I replace reference and file by completely new Credits.rtf file (and XCode shows that this reference is exists and asked me if I want to replace it)

I think that solving this must be absolutely easy, I tried to find any idea but without success

Could you help with this? Thanks in advance

[image]

Maybe you are thinking that I'm absolute moron, maybe it is bug or I dont know, but I wish to solve this and knowing how to solve same issue in future :)

Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've definitely, absolutely, certainly replaced it with a real RTF file that opens in TextEdit without fail, then you may just need to clean and rebuild your project. With the project open, press Cmd-Shift-K. When Xcode is finished, build and run and see if it changes.

If not, you'll need to post a lot more detail. Perhaps an example project somewhere shared online.

Comment: super, it working. This "clean" I will remember :) So many attempts what I try but without this one. Clean = hard-delete for reference whether I rightly understood. Thank you